# Variable is set but prints out nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am setting a variable in another viewcontroller and it is working inside didSet but in viewdidload it prints out nil

**ViewController 1**

```
    let methodView = MethodViewController()
    methodView.items = itemsSelected
    presentDetail(newVC)
```

**ViewController 2**

```
class MethodViewController: UIViewController {

    var items: [[String: Any]]? {
        didSet {
           print(items) // PRINTS OUT ITEMS NORMALLY
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(items) // PRINTS OUT NIL       
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not passing `methodView` to `presentDetails()` method. Why `presentDetail(newVC)` ?? Looks like you are setting `items` to different instance variable and presenting different view controller instance.

Comment: ` let newVC: UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "clientViewController") as! ClientViewController` This is newVC. I understand what you mean about different instances but how can I pass the variable with instantiateViewController

Comment: newVc is `ClientViewController` but you are setting `items` to `MethodViewController` ???

Comment: @Bilal post an answer, I think he needs clarifications on this

Comment: You're doing this the hard way. Use a storyboard and segues. See [this sample project](https://github.com/ryantxr/legendary-potato)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is returning nil because you are setting the items by using one instance and when you present the screen and display your methodViewController. then you pass a new instance for same. instead set the items by using the same instance which you are using to present your controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

let methodView = StackProgramViewController() //instance 1 //your case methodView
methodView.items = itemsSelected //value is set and printed


}


@IBAction func present(_ sender: Any) {

let newVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "stack") as! StackProgramViewController //instance 2 while presenting //your case newVc

newVc.items = itemsSelected //set value here with second instance nstaead of creating methodView
present(newVc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an initializer method on your class, and then pass it explicitly to the present method like so:

### MethodViewController

```
class MethodViewController: UIViewController {

    var items: [[String: Any]]?

    init(withItems items:[[String: Any]]?) {
        self.items = items
        super.init(nibName: "MethodViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(items);
    }
}
```

### Previous View Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let items = [["Stack":"Overflow"]]
        let methodView = MethodViewController(withItems: items)
        self.present(methodView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have tested it and it will print out the items passed, also note the require init() method which the compiler forces you to have. You will also need to specify the bundle and nibName depending on how you set up your views.

I should note this approach is if you aren't trying to load from the storyboard, but rather from a separate .xib file with the same name.